# Call Google Spreadsheet by bash

Tags: bash, shell, google-drive-api

I would like to call my private google spreadsheet by bash/shell. I don't want to edit it or something, only read it and put the content on the stand-output...
Is it possible?
I found a way, where I can call published projects from Google Drive, but that doesn't fit, as I have confidential data in that spreadsheet!

Also I haven't find an easy to use API solution to do that one simple thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Your script will need to do 3 things, each with curl:-

1. Use a saved Refresh Token to request an Access Token
2. Use the Access Token to fetch your spreadsheet's File resource (json)

   - Parse the json to extract the exportLinks object, and choose which format (eg. csv) you want to download
3. GET that exportLink